# Getting "Too few invocations" on unit test with spock

Tags: spock

For simplicity let's take a very simple class:

```java
public class TestingClass {

    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("Running method 1");
        method2();
    }

    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("Running method 2");
    }
}
```

Now I'm writing a simple test, which checking that when we invoke `method1()`, `method2()` is invoked:

```java
class TestingClassSpec extends Specification {
    void "method2() is invoked by method1()"() {
        given:
        def tesingClass = new TestingClass()

        when:
        tesingClass.method1()
        then:
        1 * tesingClass.method2()
    }
}
```

by executing this test, I'm getting the following error:

> Running method 1 Running method 2
>
> Too few invocations for:
>
> 1 * tesingClass.method2()   (0 invocations)

Why I'm getting this error? Printed log is show that `method2()` was invoked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `Spy` when testing interactions on real objects, see below:

```java
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class TestingClassSpec extends Specification {
    void "method2() is invoked by method1()"() {
        given:
        TestingClass tesingClass = Spy()

        when:
        tesingClass.method1()

        then:
        1 * tesingClass.method2()
    }
}

public class TestingClass {

    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("Running method 1");
        method2();
    }

    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("Running method 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Opal, thanks for your response.
Yes, I know that I can use Spy and it works just perfectly. 
I want to understand what is the logic that this code with real object doesn't work.

Comment: @AramAslanyan it won't work because you do need spock in the invocations at any level - to verify invocations you must use spies or mocks, this is how interaction testing works. You need to wrap a real object somehow with the tools provided. Is that clear?